# jQuery Validation - Using validation on click, not on submit

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I'm using (or trying to) [JQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) with WebForms/html.

I have, basically (simplifying the real html, showing only the elements):

```
<input id="txtEmail"/>
<input id="txtTicketID"/>
<a id="create" href="#">Create a new ticket</a>
<a id="find" href="#">Find this ticket</a>
```

The javascript for validation/action is here:

```
$(function() {
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        rules: {
            txtEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
                ,
                messages: {
                    required: "* enter your e-mail",
                    email: "*  invalid e-mail"
                }
            },
            txtTicketID: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "*",
                    digits: "* invalid ticket"
                }
            }
        },
        onfocusout: true,
        onkeyup: true,
        onsubmit: false,
        debug: true
    });

    $("#create").click(function() {
        if ($("#aspnetForm").valid()) {
            var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
            if (email != "")
                window.location = "CreateTicket.aspx?email=" + email;
        }
    });

    $("#find").click(function() {
        if ($("#aspnetForm").valid()) {
            var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
            var ticketID = $("#txtTicketID").val();
            if (email != "" && ticketID != "")
                window.location = "DetailEditTicket.aspx?email=" + email + "&ticketID=" + ticketID;
        }
    });
});
```

It is not working at all.. the valid() on the links click always return true, even if the fields are blank, or wrong.

When I type something, blur, etc, nothing makes validation happen.

Do you see what is missing on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `validate(rules:{})` takes options consisting of a `name:{object}` pattern, you're passing in an `id:{object}` pattern. Try:

```
<input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail"/>
<input id="txtTicketID" name="txtTicketID"/>
<a id="create" href="#">Create a new ticket</a>
<a id="find" href="#">Find this ticket</a>
```

Comment: Steerpike is correct, further, you could simplify a bit by tagging your inputs with class="required email" etc. instead of adding them as rules above.  Once you call validate on the form, the plugin will pick these up.

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed some code out but it looks like you're calling the function 'valid' but you've set it as 'validate'. So your function for validating emails and ticket ID's isn't running at all.

Comment: should I Call Validate() on the click?

Comment: .validate() is used to set up the form validation and .valid() is used to test if the form is valid. So no, .validate() is best called at initialization.